# Prove $\sigma(2^{k-1})=2^k-1$

Tags: proof-verification

Is there any way to prove this? rather than just plugging in numbers?

It's related to Mersenne Primes for anyone interested.
I only wanna know the proof to the above statement.

Thank you.

Comment: Please specify what is $\sigma$ and what are your attempts to solve the problem.

Comment: Are you trying to write $\sigma(2^{k-1})=2^k-1$?

Comment: Garry Myerson,  Yes, sorry, when I copy/pasted, it came out differently. But yes that is what I meant to write.

Comment: And did you mean to write "Gerry", when you wrote "Garry"?

Comment: Hahah, yeah I did. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Every divisor of $2^{k-1}$ is of the form $2^i$ where $0\le i\le k-1$. Sum of these divisors forms a geometric series 
$$1+2+\dots +2^{k-1}=2^k -1$$

Comment: Thank you guys Ark and Fermat!